# CXF logs not appending to Log file

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, log4j2

I want to log the Apache CXF inbound and outbound interceptors logs inside the File instead of Console

**Maven project :**

1) Created a file named 'org.apache.cxf.Logger' under META-INF\cxf and placed the below text

META-INF\cxf\org.apache.cxf.Logger

```
       org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

**2) application-context.xml:**

```
  <cxf:bus>
  <cxf:inInterceptors>
    <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:inInterceptors>
  <cxf:outInterceptors>
    <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
   </cxf:outInterceptors>
  <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
  <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
  </cxf:bus>  
<jaxrs:server id="services" address="/mysvc">   
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="myserviceImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
     <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
    </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>     
  </jaxrs:server>
  <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" id="loggingInInterceptor" />
  <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" id="loggingOutInterceptor" />
```

**3)  log4j2.xml: under src\main\resources folder**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Configuration status="warn" name="CompanyServices" packages="">
    <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="D:/temp/companyfile.log"
        filePattern="companyfile-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p [%t] %C:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p [%t] %C:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
   </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.myorg.mycompany" level="trace"
        additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.apache.cxf.interceptor" level="info" 
        additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
      </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
```

**4. pom.xml :**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

A file was getting generated and printing only my application level logs to my file. But not printing CXF interceptors logs in to the file.

Please suggest what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**step 1)** Redirect to `Slf4jLogger` as it looks like redirecting to the `Log4jLogger` [does not seem to work with Log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24931576/4201470). In addition SLF4J allows more flexibility afterwards if you ever decided to change logging framework.

**step 2)** I think the above configuration could be simplified a bit. You are adding the logging interceptors to both the CXF bus and your JAX-RS endpoint. If you only want messages to be logged for your endpoint, add them there. If not, add them to the bus as such you do not need to repeat the configuration for possible other endpoints.

Also on the endpoint you did not add the logging interceptors to the fault interceptor chains. If you basically want to log all messages it is probably easier to use the CXF `LoggingFeature`. For more [details on the difference between interceptors and features, check this blog post](https://www.codenotfound.com/2015/01/cxf-feature-vs-interceptor.html) I wrote.

**step 4)** You would need the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've created a [blog post which explains how to configure CXF for log4j2 in more detail](https://www.codenotfound.com/2015/01/jaxws-cxf-logging-request-response-soap-messages-log4j2.html).